# FTP file close query

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, ftp

I have the below logic for file retrival using FTP. Can anyone please advise if I need to explicitly close the FTP connection ? Also if the file needs to be closed? Is it a good practice to catch error while doing this kind of operation ?

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
ftp.login("UID", "PSW")
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open(filename, 'w').write)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the python docs on the ftp.quit method

> FTP.quit()
>
> Send a QUIT command to the server and close the connection. This is
>   the “polite” way to close a connection, but it may raise an exception
>   if the server responds with an error to the QUIT command. This implies
>   a call to the close() method which renders the FTP instance useless
>   for subsequent calls (see below).

The ftp docs don't say anything about closing a file handle but it is always good practice to close the files you open.